# How do you do Recursive Types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, recursion, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand how to do recursive typing in Typescript and getting a compilation error.

I have the following two functions –

- `getNestedProperty` – recursive function returns the value of nested properties for an object
- `sum` – function that takes an array of objects and sums up the value of the nested properties

```js
function getNestedProperty<T extends Record<string, T>, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: string[]): T | T[P] {
  const nestedKeys = [...keys];
  const nestedKey = nestedKeys.shift();
  if (nestedKey !== undefined) {
    return getNestedProperty(obj[nestedKey], nestedKeys) as T;
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}

export function sum<T extends number | Record<string, T>>(array: T[], keys?: string[]): number {
  const totalSum = array.reduce((accumulator: number, element: T) => {
    if (typeof element === 'number') {
      return accumulator + element;
    }
    if (keys === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`keys not passed in as an argument and type of Array is not number`);
    }
    return accumulator + +getNestedProperty(element, keys);
  }, 0);
  return totalSum;
}
```

I'm getting this error when trying to call the `sum` function

```js
const array = [
  { a: { b: 1 } }, 
  { a: { b: 3 } }, 
  { a: { b: 5 } }
];

const actual = Utils.sum(array, ['a', 'b']);
expect(actual).to.equal(1+3+5);

Error:
Argument of type '{ a: { b: number; }; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(number | Record<string, { a: { b: number; }; }>)[]'.
  Type '{ a: { b: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'number | Record<string, { a: { b: number; }; }>'.
    Type '{ a: { b: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, { a: { b: number; }; }>'.
      Property 'a' is incompatible with index signature.
        Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: number; }' but required in type '{ a: { b: number; }; }'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Your generic type constraints are strange; a constraint like `T extends number | Record<string, T>` or `T extends Record<string, T>` is unlikely to be satisfied by any type that isn't already known to be recursive.  Personally I'd probably just make your functions nongeneric and have `sum` operate on a known recursive type as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0zyxw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: On the other hand if you *need* generics, then you will need to define some deeply recursive conditional types that describe deep indexing, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE8vgW).  Would you prefer to see this version instead in an answer?  Let me know one way or another.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jcalz! Your first playground link makes sense and is similar to I had previously. I was just wondering if there is a way to code both functions without an explicit any type.

Comment: Sure you can avoid `any` but you will almost certainly need some kind of type assertion for such deeply nested types.  [This version](https://tsplay.dev/NdvoyW) is one way.  Would an answer explaining this be acceptable to you?  If so I'll write one up (but it might not be until 8 or 9 hours from now because it's my bedtime now)

Comment: Yes that would work, appreciate the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function whose call signature looks like

```
declare function foo<T extends number | Record<string, T>>(t: T): void;
```

is that when you call it with some object literal like

```
foo({ a: 1 }) // error!
```

the compiler doesn't use the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `number | Record<string, T>` as an *inference site* for `T` (as suggested but never adopted in [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)). Instead, it infers `T` just from the value passed in, and then *checks* it against the constraint.

So in the above call, `T` is inferred as `{a: 1}` because that's the type of the `{a: 1}` literal.  And then it's checked against `number | Record<string, T>` which is `number | Record<string, {a: 1}>`.  And `{a: 1}` does *not* extend `number | Record<string, {a: 1}>`, and so the value doesn't meet the constraint and there's an error.

The only way the call would succeed is if the passed in value was already known to be recursive in the desired way, but that's not going to happen if you're passing in object literals.

So we need a different approach.

---

Unless you need generics, you could instead make the functions non-generic and have them act on the appropriately recursive type when necessary, like

```
type Summable = number | { [k: string]: Summable };
```

The value from before will therefore be checked against that type, which succeeds:

```
const val: Summable = { a: 1 }; // okay
```

So you could refactor to:

```
function sum(array: Summable[], keys?: string[]): number {
  const totalSum = array.reduce((accumulator: number, element) => {
    if (typeof element === 'number') {
      return accumulator + element;
    }
    if (keys === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`keys not passed in as an argument and type of Array is not number`);
    }
    return accumulator + Number(getNestedProperty(element, keys));
  }, 0);
  return totalSum;
}
```

And maybe

```
function getNestedProperty(obj: unknown, keys: string[]): unknown {
  const nestedKeys = [...keys];
  const nestedKey = nestedKeys.shift();
  if ((nestedKey !== undefined) && (typeof obj === "object") && obj && (nestedKey in obj)) {
    const o = obj as Record<string, unknown>;
    return getNestedProperty(o[nestedKey], nestedKeys);
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

where we're just going to say that the input and output types of `getNestedProperty(obj, keys)` is `unknown`, because there's not really anything more useful to do without making the function generic.

Note that I'd probably refactor the implementation to

```
function getNestedProperty(obj: unknown, keys: string[]): unknown {
  return keys.reduce((acc, k) =>
    typeof acc === "object" && acc && k in acc ?
      (acc as Record<string, unknown>)[k] : acc,
    obj);
}
```

unless you have some need for it to be recursive.

---

If you *do* need to make the function generic, then you'd have to go through the relatively painful process of describing exactly what the functions will do.  For example, `getNestedProperty()` could look like

```
type DeepIdx<T, K extends PropertyKey[]> =
  K extends [infer K0, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
  K0 extends keyof T ? DeepIdx<T[K0], KR> : T : T;

function getNestedProperty<T, K extends PropertyKey[]>(
  obj: T,
  keys: [...K]
): DeepIdx<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce<any>((acc, k) =>
    typeof acc === "object" && acc && k in acc ? acc[k] : acc,
    obj);
}
```

although I'm not going to digress further to explain exactly how that works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KFWQbEDzarPfrwGTyJBQQzA4qRr22n0Qa4HI5Qanm86ua63YCGEysJ4wl1uySySSYG1+1Kp+a-CD-QGM+CGMRCWusYKlo2sTwQPWQYCSCHeSv06SIgKqiAIjTjjiSP1ogDkQ-LW9yBGV9Ne7wUIJ7fdsSAA1KuIBPJE76dkpSR5wyvvpUQaJPwmC52wPV9eEkAALEodlICBIIAUWKWw-AAA0-Ug6yQOAoCgdsKTPfQQDPVhXEMddUmAWgVTVFcAEEWwpfRtg3Xc2EQ2VgMVZ8kBPD5iQvEB+xvJBGjLNg-GGUZxnbaZZFmVgFj8Md73XHNjhCVij2yTwAAY1OPEZT1hOsG0MJ8FWjXhqw3YRWEjJsLilANghSIwMmyDT7NSRykGcpAAGZXKySV1IcvAvOCABWfzoSuOVoQspE3kwJskzAFNrPmTwLi3EAt08LcjC3G4TKQatZD1b4MFkVxGQSjAQjMxV4jIepKCQNpgA6LpD2eOFkAAEQgCAYHoWhNDUTwAGkNG0XR9CkmSFnGo5rhncEpUmrQdDI-QLhcFgK3GzTPG+Y7dtMcbLCmza9CQOa5nmRb5muUVaXUg7LpmskjhXdRqSQfrBuG0bVAuA6rgmywZ2CdQoZi5VY3jIYRjGRxJJmO6xqQdbpq2m60dk+6lqufwpSxKHAvpT9gguY7vnGq5oVuf6hpGjHxpnLqYS4z5czbDsIGUfD5n8LswT9KF1JIHqVxBTcDUxVYcTxUkZdJclKRl36QWFUVxWRcnnxlIqGuVHq-oGmBWXZZQsau2a8YWwnPAANRWtb3pxnbmDOzT3eu278Yeo6Tq9-aLo2j7-Ydx6rme9yLkmHDMc0q0zcGy27GtyxnZnLIxSQJ2ivhwZE0Ma3fbt6S7oe65bKJ1K01Ti2bAz8bPCY1hvGzT7jipmm6dr5lSPmEthIrDnni55s0t5gEICBc8wF7PjbEHUfRzXSdp2Ahel-429rzE5GJkjxYFIfZSoBCLS1OhY3nXkN0rJsg07KCjyQu84M3LfwMnOCPzc4BXcr-UKSAIqAKirDe+rpGISSmDMJsh84En2SO-P+IV4CeVoMEdEOp4B4kAf5DKuD0SeHREYUhGJ8FkNoOiQq0ICjFQfrAlG8DpIFi5LFB+pUIDlUqn4dqrC5rfFrAAVRgDJAAwiALCfhVKhgxFRKgkj0RmRIMlPwFx0ieAAEyeB8oVBR4ZIzQg0RcYKwZPDBR0RpEKgYAFgyQBcEhhjGHGKjMqMxFjbHWJ8e-BxsoFFsBKCOKasw4zYSfvMJAK525QFMcmLRuj9GOOcSAOhgTGHBNsKOTQ4SJhTxsiuXAgZ27G2qPVIgWQgA)